# Openstreetmap: getting data of color #dddde8?

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson

How could we get data set with color #dddde8 on the map?
For example:

[Openstreetmap example](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/764430414#map=19/48.87626/2.36981)

Tried a lot with "query feature" but could never approach it.

Thanks

Edit: for clarification, I am working on a study for a small district of Paris. I need the shape of the pedestrian way to make some calculus. I never could gather data precise enough to know the width of the pedestrian way, or at least their shapes. And this is my exact need.

#### Edit - final:

To sum up: this data is not present. So nothing to grab.

Comment: That probably is the layer , standard layer , Cycle Map , Transport Map. Not sure , could you please elaborate more about the arguments that you are providing.

Comment: OSM data has no color. The renderer or the renderer stylesheet decides how features are rendered and what color they get assigned. Which specific element are you looking for? Your question remains rather vague.

Answer (score 1):

Larger pedestrian areas in OpenStreetMap usually use the [`highway=pedestrian`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dpedestrian) [tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) or [`highway=footway`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dfootway) + `area=yes`.

You can use [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to query these features as long as the area is not too large:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  way["highway"="pedestrian"]({{bbox}});
  relation["highway"="pedestrian"]({{bbox}});


  way["highway"="footway"]["area"="yes"]({{bbox}});
  relation["highway"="footway"]["area"="yes"]({{bbox}});
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

You can [view the result at overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1f0D), a web frontend for Overpass API. Also check the export button if want to download the data.

Comment: I did that but you can notice that not all the pedestrian ways are returned. I will need to go the long way with geometry and crossings of roads.. not good..

Comment: Which ones are missing? If you are interested in each tiny footway that has been added to OSM, remove the `["area"="yes"]` from the `["highway"="footway"]` lines and also add `way["highway"="path"]({{bbox}});` and `way["highway"="cycleway"]({{bbox}});`. That should return all foot ways that exist in OSM.
Note that there is also the `sidewalk=*` key that describes if a road as a sidewalk. Your original question is still rather vague so I'm still not sure what you are actually interested in.

Comment: I tried your update and still the issue is that not all of them have been registered. So I will have to follow a bruteforce method.

Comment: Can you name an example of missing data?

Comment: Sure: please look at it here : https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1f1m, I cannot get the sidewalks of the Rue Dupont des Loges

Comment: This is because this data is not present in OSM. Nobody added it to OSM yet. As you can see, there is no sidewalk rendered on the map and also the road (https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/719115071) doesn't have a `sidewalk` tag. However, feel free to add this data to OSM: https://learnosm.org/en/beginner/

Comment: That was my conclusion as well. I will need to go the long route. Scai, thank you for your time ;) +1